# Graph execution error: Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to train a Neural Network with 550 voices.

First I create the model,then I create the first hidden layer and the dense layers and finally the output layer

```
modelo = Sequential()

modelo.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape=(40,) ))

modelo.add(layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'))
modelo.add(layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'))
modelo.add(layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'))

    enter code here

modelo.add(layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
```

Here I train the model with 100 epochs for the system to run through 100 times.

```
historial = modelo.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, verbose = 1, batch_size =32, validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
loss,acc= modelo.evaluate(x_test, y_test,verbose=1)
print('loss:{0} - Acurracy:{1}'.format(loss,acc))
```

After running the code, I get the following error message

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-8e2d34ffebba> in <module>()
      1 #Entrenando el modelo
      2 #Le di 100 epocas lo que significa que el 70% de 550 voces de entrenamiento se van a pasar por el sistema 100 veces.
----> 3 historial = modelo.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, verbose = 1, batch_size =32, validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
      4 loss,acc= modelo.evaluate(x_test, y_test,verbose=1)
      5 print('loss:{0} - Acurracy:{1}'.format(loss,acc))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
      handler_func(fileobj, events)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 452, in _handle_events
      self._handle_recv()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 481, in _handle_recv
      self._run_callback(callback, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 431, in _run_callback
      callback(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
      return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
      handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
      if self.run_code(code, result):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-44-c79155e9f72c>", line 3, in <module>
      historial = modelo.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, verbose = 1, batch_size =128, validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
      y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1863, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5203, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      labels=target, logits=output)
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
Received a label value of 4 which is outside the valid range of [0, 3).  Label values: 3 2 1 0 1 4 3 1 1 4 3 4 1 1 3 3 4 1 2 4 4 0 4 0 4 1 0 4 0 1 2 4
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1858]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing. It looks like you can have only 4 categories at the output layer with values between 0 and 3. You are specifying value 4 in the output layer and it is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

**I faced the same error exactly. After a long search and many tries I found a solution
You can reduce the size of an image or batch this good solution; if you don't want to use this you have two options based on what you using GPU or CPU : if you use GPU, put this code before running your code :**

```
import os
import torch
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
print(f"Using GPU is CUDA:{os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']}")

for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
    info = torch.cuda.get_device_properties(i)
    print(f"CUDA:{i} {info.name}, {info.total_memory / 1024 ** 2}MB")

device = torch.device("cuda:0")
```

#**or if you use CPU, put this code :**

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"    
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

**will be working... good luck**